# Which Context? To avoid Memory Leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-context

I know this has been asked many times but still many new developers like me finds it difficult.To avoid `memory leaks` which `context` should be used?.
Somewhere i found that we should `getApplicationContext()` and somewhere that try to use `context-activity` as possible.Also http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html says

```
Try using the context-application instead of a context-activity
```

For eg

Which Context to pass to `RecyclerView Adapter` or to a `Custom Dialog Class`

One way i found is to pass context to adapter in this way

```
recyclerview.setAdapter(new YourAdapter(new WeakReference<Activity>(ActivityName).get()));
```

Is my way of passing context is right?

Please do a give detailed explanation so that others also gets benefitted.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Which Context to pass to RecyclerView Adapter or to a Custom Dialog Class

When dealing with UI concerns, always pass the `Activity`.

> Is my way of passing context is right?

You should not need a `WeakReference` to the `Activity` for use in a `RecyclerView`.

> To avoid memory leaks which context should be used?

That cannot be answered in general. The simplest basic rule is: use `Application` as a `Context` when you are concerned that the `Context` might be held in `static` scope, such as in an object referenced by a `static` data member, or such as in a thread. Otherwise, use a more-focused `Context` (e.g., your `Activity`, your `Service`).

[Dave Smith's blog post on contexts](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) is the best single-page resource on the subject that I have found.

Comment: But if i use a weakref context will it create any problem?

Comment: @SonaliPawar: You might have some performance-related issues, due to constantly going through locks.

Comment: what if sir i have to do Network related jobs or show dialogs from adapter, will activity context be suitable?

Comment: @SonaliPawar: As I wrote in my answer, when dealing with UI concerns, like a dialog, always use the `Activity`. "Network related jobs" do not have an intrinsic need for a `Context`. What matters is not that they are "network related", but what they are doing and how long they are taking. There are **many** patterns for asynchronous work.